# How to connect sybase with laravel 8.0?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-8

I want to install sybase with laravel version 8.0. I used below command for installing,

```
composer require uepg/laravel-sybase
```

this gives below error. I dont know what’s this mean.
Can anyone explain me what does this mean and how can I resolve this type of error.

> Problem 1
> – Installation request for uepg/laravel-sybase ^2.4 -> satisfiable by uepg/laravel-sybase[2.4.0].
> – Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v8.2.0
> – Conclusion: don’t install laravel/framework v8.2.0
> – uepg/laravel-sybase 2.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.|5.7.|5.8.|6.|7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
> – don’t install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don’t install laravel/framework v8.2.0
> – don’t install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don’t install laravel/framework v8.2.0
> – don’t install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don’t install laravel/framework v8.2.0

Comment: `uepg/laravel-sybase 2.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.|5.7.|5.8.|6.|7` is your exact reason - just read the error... It does not support ^8.x. Or perhaps, `composer update` and try again. Perhaps your ` illuminate/support` is outdated. Alternatively, download the files manually, alter the composer to ignore the version and fix any errors to upgrade it yourself to support 8.x

Answer (score 0):

Do not run `composer require uepg/laravel-sybase`  directly in the console. Follow these

open your **composer.json** and add `"uepg/laravel-sybase": "~2.0"`

the run `composer update`

after all these in **config/app.php** add

```
Uepg\LaravelSybase\SybaseServiceProvider::class
```

and in **config/app.php** add

```
'SybaseBlueprint' => Uepg\LaravelSybase\Database\Schema\Blueprint::class
```

This works for me.

Comment: not working.... getting this error Class 'Agomez\ODBCDriver\ODBCDriverServiceProvider' not found

Comment: use `composer require agomez/laravel-odbc-driver`.

Comment: can you see below link. I updated errors and question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022463/getting-error-while-migrating-laravel-7-to-8