# Getting error while migrating laravel 7 to 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

I am using library **upeg/sybase 2.1**. when I am upgrading laravel 8 , i am getting below error. How can I resolve this error?

Getting error while applyig command `composer update`

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "abram/laravel-odbc": "dev-master",
    "agomez/laravel-odbc-driver": "^1.0",
    "alipek/rtf2html": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "google/recaptcha": "^1.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0.1",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.4",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "uepg/laravel-sybase": "^2.1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
```

> Problem 1
> - Installation request for uepg/laravel-sybase ^2.1.0 -> satisfiable by uepg/laravel-sybase[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.3.0, 2.3
> .1, 2.4.0].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[8.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.2, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.3, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.0.4, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.1.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.10.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.11.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.11.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.11.2, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.12.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.12.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.12.2, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.12.3, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.13.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.14.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.15.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.16.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.16.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.17.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.17.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.17.2, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.18.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.18.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.19.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.2.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.20.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.20.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.21.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.22.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.22.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.23.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.23.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.24.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.25.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.26.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.26.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.3.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.4.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.5.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.6.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.7.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.7.1, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.8.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v8.9.0, 5.7.x-dev].
> - Conclusion: install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
> - Installation request for laravel/framework ^8.0.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.11.
> 2, v8.12.0, v8.12.1, v8.12.2, v8.12.3, v8.13.0, v8.14.0, v8.15.0, v8.16.0, v8.16.1, v8.17.0, v8.17.1, v8.17.2, v8.18.0, v8.18.1, v8.19.0, v8.2.0, v8.20.0, v8.20.1, v8.21.0, v
> 8.22.0, v8.22.1, v8.23.0, v8.23.1, v8.24.0, v8.25.0, v8.26.0, v8.26.1, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to install `uepg/laravel-sybase` on your laravel 8, but the latest version of that package only support up to laravel 7 only. But the master branch allow you to use laravel 8, so try update your composer.json to `"uepg/laravel-sybase": "dev-master"`

or try command:

```
composer require uepg/laravel-sybase dev-master
```

Comment: thanks man this is working... well what means of dev-master? can you explain me ?

Comment: dev-master is the latest development version of the package but not released yet as new version. Usually still active development and maybe not tested so can have bugs

Comment: maybe yes, but as far I trying some packages I never see bug  even on dev-master. I think it's better than cant install. if new version coming up just change it to the new version. But I see, that package no update since oct 2020, maybe hiatus or abandoned

Answer (score 2):

use latest version

try `"uepg/laravel-sybase": "^2.4.0"` then run `composer update`

or

```sh
composer require uepg/laravel-sybase "^2.4.0"
```

ref link

https://github.com/uepg/laravel-sybase/tags

https://github.com/uepg/laravel-sybase/commit/7f5d8d2ecf78cae08f18e5d342e504a5a641ca4b

Comment: have i need to add illuminate/support as well?

Comment: uepg/laravel-sybase 2.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.|5.7.|5.8.|6.|7.*

Comment: or may be run `composer install`

Comment: actually i am new to laravel. can you explain me which changes may  i have to do in composer.json as described in error?

Comment: so sybase latest version doesn't support to laravel-8?

Comment: then why am i getting errors.. it gives me error as described in my question